# Воспроизвести mp3 файл на Windows CE 5.0 с помощью C# .NET CF 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, windows-ce

Пишу приложение под Windows CE 5.0 на C# .NET CF 2.0. Воспроизвожу wav-файлы через библиотеку CoreDll.DLL.
Но есть необходимость воспроизводить mp3 файлы.

Как это можно реализовать?